# How do I access elements in a dictionary based on their position?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Every week I plan on sending out an email to each member of a group with the tasks that they have yet to complete.

Each member has their `ID` and `name` in a dictionary, for example:

```
143:John Smith

208:Mary Green

222:Sue Brown
```

I plan on going through the list of items for each member, and adding items that are assigned to them to a table to email them.

Everything seems to work, but I'm stuck on actually looping through each member. I need the name to check if they are assigned to that item, which I've been trying to do with an index like so:

```
then set Variable: memberIndex to 0
```

and then to retrieve:

`Get([%Variable: memberIndex%]) from Variable: Members (output to memberName)`

But this doesn't seem to work, and nothing I've found has helped. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble looping through all items in your response refer the following syntax.

[image]